# is there a way to change the date format in php?

Tags: php, datetime, chart.js

i have a chartjs charts that display the dateformat of

```
'm-d-Y H:i:s'
```

thats how the dates come out of the sql table as, but i need them to appear as d-m-y on the charts.

my model :

```
class chartData extends Entity
{
    public static function findBy(
        \DateTime $StartDate,
        \DateTime $EndDate
    ): array
    {
        $params = [
            $StartDate->format('m-d-Y H:i:s'),
            $EndDate->format('m-d-Y H:i:s'),
        ];
        return self::hydrate(DB::select('EXEC Table @StartDate = ?, @EndDate = ?',
            $params
        ));
    }

}
```

my controller :

```
public function index (Request $request)
{
    if (!$request->input('StartDate') && !$request->input('EndDate')) {
        $StartTime = Carbon::now()->subDays(7);
        $EndTime = Carbon::now();
    } else {
        $StartTime = Carbon::parse($request->input('StartDate'));
        $EndTime = Carbon::parse($request->input('EndDate'));
    }



    $Activity = chartData::findBy(
        Carbon::parse($StartTime),
        Carbon::parse($EndTime)
    );
```

i cant simply do a ->format('d-m-y') as i get thrown errors. does anyone have any idea of how to reformat this so the date will appear as day/month/year ?

UPDATE:

taking advise, i have changed my chartjs to include the date formatting advised:

```
  var ctx = document.getElementById("Chart").getContext('2d');
 var recentActivityChart = new Chart(ctx, {
     type: 'bar',
     data: {
         labels: [],
         datasets: [{
             label: 'hours',
             data: [],
             barThickness: 12,
             fill: true,
             backgroundColor: "rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)",
             borderColor: "rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)",
             borderWidth: 1,
         }]
     },
     options: {
         animation: {
             duration: 1000,
             easing: "linear",
         },
         responsive: true,
         maintainAspectRatio: true,
         legend: {
             display: false,
             position: 'bottom',
             usePointStyle: true,
             labels: {
                 fontColor: "grey",
                 usePointStyle: true,
             },
         },
         scales: {
             yAxes: [{
                 gridLines: {
                     display: true,
                     borderDash: [8, 4],
                 },
                 scaleLabel: {
                     display: true,
                     labelString: 'hours',
                 },
                 ticks: {
                     beginAtZero: false,
                 }
             }],
             xAxes: [{
                 type: 'time',
                 time: {
                     parser: 'labels', // define date format that matches the php data
                     unit: 'day',
                     displayFormats: {
                         day: 'DD-MM-YYYY'
                     },
                     tooltipFormat: 'DD-MM-YYYY'
                 },
                 gridLines: {
                     scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
                     display: false,
                 },
                 ticks: {
                     beginAtZero: false,


                 }
             }]
         },
     }
 });
```

this works as the dates now appear at dd-mm-yyy. however, the chart now begins in 1970 instead of when the data in the sql table actually begins.
[image: chartjs chart showing incorrect dates,]

any idea of how to resolve this?

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is best handled in the frontend rather than in the backend.

You should deine your xAxis as a [time cartesian axis](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html) as follows.

```
options: {
  ...
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      type: 'time',
      time: {
        parser: '', // define date format that matches the php data
        unit: 'day',
        displayFormats: {
          day: 'D-M-YYYY'
        },
        tooltipFormat: 'D-M-YYYY'
      }
      ...
    }]
  }
  ...
}
```

See [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) to find out about format strings that may be used for [`time.parser`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#parser), [`time.displayFormats`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#configuration-options) and [`time.tooltipFormat`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#configuration-options).

> Note that Chart.js internally uses [Moment.js](https://github.com/moment/moment/) for the functionality of the [time axis](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html). Therefore you should use the [bundled version](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/installation.html#bundled-build) of Chart.js that includes Moment.js in a single file.

Comment: ive added this into my chart 
`type: 'time',
                 time: {
                     parser: 'labels', // define date format that matches the php data
                     unit: 'day',
                     displayFormats: {
                         day: 'DD-MM-YYYY'
                     },
                     tooltipFormat: 'DD-MM-YYYY'
                 },`

the chart is formatting in the correct way but for some reason it begins in 1970. the labels data is pulled from a database row that has dates from 2020 so im not sure why its showing 1970 -2020

Comment: @codingWithNikki: the `parser` property must contain a pattern that matches the date received from the php backend.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
i've managed to have it display correctly! this is the updated chart: I did not need the parser, it understood without what needed to be passed through.

```
  var ctx = document.getElementById("recentChart").getContext('2d');
 var recentChart = new Chart(ctx, {
     type: 'bar',
     data: {
         labels: [],
         datasets: [{
             label: 'hours',
             data: [],
             barThickness: 12,
             fill: true,
             backgroundColor: "rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)",
             borderColor: "rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)",
             borderWidth: 1,
         }]
     },
     options: {
         animation: {
             duration: 1000,
             easing: "linear",
         },
         responsive: true,
         maintainAspectRatio: true,
         legend: {
             display: false,
             position: 'bottom',
             usePointStyle: true,
             labels: {
                 fontColor: "grey",
                 usePointStyle: true,
             },
         },
         scales: {
             yAxes: [{
                 gridLines: {
                     display: true,
                     borderDash: [8, 4],
                 },
                 scaleLabel: {
                     display: true,
                     labelString: 'hours',
                 },
                 ticks: {
                     beginAtZero: false,
                 }
             }],
             xAxes: [{
                 type: 'time',
                 time: {
                     unit: 'day',
                     displayFormats: {
                                 day: 'DD-MM-YYYY'
                             },
                 },
                 gridLines: {
                     scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
                     display: false,
                 },
                 ticks: {
                     beginAtZero: true,

                 }
             }]
         },
     }
 });
```

dates now show up correctly and not from 1970.